# Having multiple fields using google's autocomplete api

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Greetings fellow coders,

I'm working on a form where there is a dynamic number of fields that would benefit from google's autocomplete API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

In the end I'd like to implement this with angular's ng-repeat, but for now I'd be happy with just not having to create a static variable for each input field in the form. (the form could be up to 20+ fields).

Has anybody done anything like this, or have any clever ideas on how to do it? I'm fairly comfortable with Javascript, but perhaps I'm missing something here.

Thanks!

Comment: can't you get all elements with a class instead of this line where you getElementById    */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),

Comment: No, because the api is looking for a specific element, not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a while longer I figured what I think is the easiest solution. By passing in the HTMLelement through an "onFocus" to an initializer, and then building the autocomplete along with geolocating/whatever I want to do with it then, I can continue to dynamically add fields, even after the initial DOM load.

`function initialize(e) {
        console.log(e);
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
           (e), { }
        );
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
              position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
              autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
            geolocation));
        });
      }}`